# Java : What is the most appropriate Design Pattern in this situation?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have this situation :

- Event 1 (Trigger) : Component **A** sends information abt **data1** and **data2**, to the component **B**;
- Component **B** deduces **data3** from **data2**;
- Event 2 (Result) : Component **B** sends information about **data1** and **data3**, to the component **C**.

Which design pattern to apply here? Is it **Handler Pattern** or **Chain of Responsibility** or **Command Pattern** or another?

Can you give me apply the design you suggest to this situation?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: I don't know. I down vote then.

Comment: Half of the [design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) out there can be used to implement the behavior that you require. What is the *context* of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain of responsibility is probably what would align most closely to your description with Component A being in charge of B and B being in charge of C.

However if the design patters are what are confusing you it might be easier to look at it through and Event/Result design with A resulting to B if successful then likewise B resulting to C if successful this would also open it up to you being able to create a more abstract/generic error handling if either of them fail.

Though its hard to get into specifics without more information on your project.

Comment: Ok, sir. I'm going to do an edit for more specifications.

Comment: HeHeHe.. My expectations say it is useless to do an EDIT. One missing close vote and the question will be blocked. Thank you for the try. It seems your explainations fit the situation. +1